# How to reintroduce the meaning of special symbols in python without modifying the original string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code:

```
    a = "Hello,\\nWorld!"
    print(a)
```

Prints:

```
    Hello,\nWorld!
```

Sure enough.
But how do I reintroduce the specialness of newline symbol and print :

```
    Hello,
    World!
```

without making any changes to the original string. like :

```
    a = "Hello,\nWorld!"
```

I am asking this because a certain function (over which I have no control) is returning a string like:

```
    Hello,\\nWorld!
```

Which i would like to print to the screen (with formatting) as

```
    Hello,
    World!
```

Comment: Why not to run `print(a.replace('\\n', '\n'))` ? This does not strictly answer the question, since you change the string, but I am not sure if there is another way or whether you really need another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode your string using `string_escape`:

```
a = "Hello,\\nWorld!"
print(a)
# Hello,\nWorld!
print(a.decode("string_escape"))
# Hello,
# World!
```

**UPDATE** - Since you didn't specify the version immediately, the above works with Python 2.x because its `str` object is already what `bytes` is in Python 3.x. For Python 3.x strings you'd have to encode them first to `bytes` and then decode them using `unicode_escape`, or let the `codecs` module do that for you:

```
import codecs

a = "Hello,\\nWorld!"
print(a)
# Hello,\nWorld!
print(codecs.getdecoder('unicode_escape')(a)[0])
# Hello,
# World!
```

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying the version.My bad! Thanx for the Update with the python-3.x version. Totally solves my problem. :)

Answer (score -1):

This seems much simpler.

```
s="Hello,\\nWorld!"

def spl(s):
    return s.replace('\\n','\n')

print(spl(s))
print(s)
```

Just create a function which returns the replaced string. And then print it.

output:

```
Hello,
World!
Hello,\nWorld!
```

Also you don't have to change your original string.

Comment: This is a nice hack that also totally works. Thanx! :)

Comment: It certainly did help me but the solution is a little illusive to the bigger problem one might be trying to solve behind this question (as I was). Cheers!